# Glossaries-extra: Adding glossaries package to "Clas­sicTh­e­sis" template by Dr. André Miede v. 4.6

Tags: classicthesis, glossaries-extra

I have been using LaTeX the "Clas­sicTh­e­sis" template by Dr. André Miede v. 4.6, for my thesis document. I require to add Lists of definitions, abbreviations, symbols to this template. I was trying to use"glossaries-extra package". However, I receive the following error on the document.

"This document is incomplete. The external file associated with the glossary ‘abbreviations’
(which should be called ClassicThesis.gls-abr) hasn’t been created.
Check the contents of the file ClassicThesis.glo-abr. If it’s empty, that means
you haven’t indexed any of your entries in this glossary (using commands like
\gls or \glsadd) so this list can’t be generated. If the file isn’t empty, the document
build process hasn’t been completed.
You may need to rerun LATEX. If you already have, it may be that TEX’s
shell escape doesn’t allow you to run makeindex. Check the transcript file
ClassicThesis.log. If the shell escape is disabled, try one of the following:
 Run the external (Lua) application:
makeglossaries-lite.lua "ClassicThesis"
 Run the external (Perl) application:
makeglossaries "ClassicThesis"
Then rerun LATEX on this document.
This message will be removed once the problem has been fix"

Comment: Have you tried running the commands mentioned at the end of the error message? Which commands do you use to compile the document?

Comment: Is your issue solved? How?